# Email template spacing breaks in Outlook

Tags: html, email, html-table, outlook, html-email

I'm building an email template and despite my efforts to use the most barebone, 2005 kind of HTML I could think of, when I try to use the template in Outlook, the spacing gets completely messed up. A simple code like this:

```html
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"></head><body>

<table align="center" cellspacing=”0” cellpadding=”0” width="768" style="border:1px solid black">

<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="24"><td><font face="Arial" size="5" color="#ff6200"><b>Lorem ipsum?</b></font></td></tr>
<tr height="10"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="100"><td><table><td width="280"><font face="Arial" size="4"><center> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br /><br />tempor incididunt ut labore et </center></font></td></table></td></tr>
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="36"><td><table><td width="420"><font face="Arial" size="3"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</center></font></td></table></td></tr>
<tr height="7"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="20"><td><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><font face="Arial" size="3" color="#ff6200"><b>consectetur</b></font></a></td></tr>
<tr height="27"><td></td></tr>
<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr align="center" height="170" bgcolor="#f2f2f2"><td><center><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#000000" style="line-height: 1.8">
olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br /><br style="line-height: 10%" />
Lorem:<br /></font>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#ff6200" style="line-height: 1.8">eu fugiat nulla pariatur</font></a><br />
<font face="Arial" size="1" color="#000000" style="line-height: 1.8">esse cillum dolor<br />
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</font></center></td></tr>


</table>

</body></html>
```

Renders correctly in both Firefox and IE for me, looking like this:
[image]

However, when inserted as text into Outlook 2016, it looks like this:
[image]

(also, here's how it looks highlighted, where some of the additional spacing may be seen:)
[image]

Basically every vertical spacing gets messed up. How do I fix it? Since it renders correctly in *Internet Explorer*, I'd hoped it'd work in Outlook but seems like it's not the case.

Comment: `However, when inserted as text into Outlook 2016, it looks like this` dont use insert as text in outlook. Use a service like mail service like mailchimp or similar to send emails for testing. Responsive emails and conditional code will not work when HTML is added as text.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<tr>` instead of `<font>` and `<br>` . So that you can get your expected space

```html
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"></head><body>

<table align="center" cellspacing=”0” cellpadding=”0” width="768" style="border:1px solid black">

<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="24"><td><font face="Arial" size="5" color="#ff6200"><b>Lorem ipsum?</b></font></td></tr>
<tr height="10"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="100"><td><table><td width="280"><font face="Arial" size="4"><center> adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod<br /><br />tempor incididunt ut labore et </center></font></td></table></td></tr>
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr height="24"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="36"><td><table><td width="420"><font face="Arial" size="3"><center>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</center></font></td></table></td></tr>
<tr height="7"><td></td></tr>
<tr align="center" height="20"><td><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><font face="Arial" size="3" color="#ff6200"><b>consectetur</b></font></a></td></tr>
<tr height="27"><td></td></tr>
<!-- ----------------------- -->
<tr align="center" height="170" bgcolor="#f2f2f2"><td><center><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#000000" style="line-height: 1.8">
olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br /><br style="line-height: 10%" />
Lorem:<br /></font>
<a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><font face="Arial" size="1" color="#ff6200" style="line-height: 1.8">eu fugiat nulla pariatur</font></a><br />
<font face="Arial" size="1" color="#000000" style="line-height: 1.8">esse cillum dolor<br />
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</font></center></td></tr>


<tr>
  <td style="border-collapse: collapse; color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-smoothing: antialiased; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding-top:9px; ">
   olore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<br /><br style="line-height: 10%" />
Lorem:<br />
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="border-collapse: collapse; color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-smoothing: antialiased; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding-top:9px; ">
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">eu fugiat nulla pariatur
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="border-collapse: collapse; color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-smoothing: antialiased; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding-top:9px; ">
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">esse cillum dolor</a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="border-collapse: collapse; color: #717171; font-family: 'Verdana', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-smoothing: antialiased; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom: 15px; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; padding-top:9px; ">
   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</a>
  </td>
</tr>


</table>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how does this answer use the method you mention? I still see `<br />`'s and `<font>`'s all around here.

Comment: I have added extra row below your code. when you use `td` you can give expected padding. For example
`<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align: top; padding-top:9px; ">
   content
  </td>
</tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2016 sets TDs at a minimum of 17px high. To avoid this, set line-height and font-size to 1px (or the desired size). This is how I build all my spacers lately. For example:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"> 
<tr>
    <td height="20" width="100%" style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 20px;">
    &nbsp;
    </td>
</tr>
```

If all you need is vertical space between list items, use margin-bottom. Don’t use padding, as Outlook will not support it.

Microsoft Office styles (MSO styles) will tighten up your lines just a bit. If your spacing seems off, give it a try. Just add “mso-line-height-rule:exactly;” directly before the line-height style, inline or embedded.

Here's more info about spacing in HTML emails if you need it! https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/spacing-techniques-in-html-email/#utm_source=Blog&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=LeadGen_2018&utm_term=development

Edit:

I'd say this is probably something that needs to be handled with additional inline CSS. Potentially adding `mso-table-lspace: 0px; mso-table-rspace: 0px;` may help. If they're worried any of their inline CSS is being overwritten, they could apply `!important` to the end of each.

e.g. `mso-table-lspace: 0px !important; mso-table-rspace: 0px !important;`

The items the above, are usually applied to these HTML elements in the CSS applied in the `<head>` tag of an email and can be applied inline to each tag they're having trouble with:

`table { border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0px; mso-table-rspace: 0px; }`
`td, a, span { border-collapse: collapse; mso-line-height-rule: exactly; }`

All of those are used one way or another to prevent Outlook from adding additional padding to tables (`<table>`) and table cells (`<td>`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regretfully, `<tr><td height="7" style="font-size: 7px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 7px;">&nbsp;</td></tr>` has the same effect as `<tr height="7"><td></td></tr>` - it works in the browser but gets visibly larger in Outlook :(